# .NET Remoting RegisterWellKnownServiceType with a specfic channel when there are multiple channels available

Tags: remoting, .net-remoting, tcpchannel

I want to know if it is possible to register a well known service on the remoting server to a particular channel and not on all the available channels.

My code is as follows:

I created 2 separate tcpchannels on the remoting server with the following code

```
IDictionary rcProperties1 = new Hashtable();
rcProperties1["port"] = "1688";
rcProperties1["name"] = "tcp1";
TcpChannel tcp1 = new TcpChannel(rcProperties1, null, null);

IDictionary rcProperties2 = new Hashtable();
rcProperties2["port"] = "1689";
rcProperties2["name"] = "tcp2";
TcpChannel tcp2 = new TcpChannel(rcProperties2, null, null);

//--------------------------------------------------
// Register tcp channels
//--------------------------------------------------
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcp1, false);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcp2, false);
```

Then I hosted 2 remote objects with the following

```
Type rt = typeof(wxMessage);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        rt, "Classes/wxMessage.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

rt = typeof(wxType);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        rt, "Classes/wxType.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

On the client, I call the remote objects through Activator.GetObject(...)

```
string uri = "tcp://localhost:1688/";

IConcrete1 objMessageRemote = (IConcrete1)Activator.GetObject(
        typeMessageLocal, uri + "Classes/wxMessage.rem");

IConcrete2 objTypeRemote = (IConcrete2)Activator.GetObject(
        typeTypeLocal, uri + "Classes/wxType.rem");
```

The thing is, it doesn't matter if I set the uri port to 1688 or 1689, I can still retrieve the remote objects.

What I want to do is to have the server host a certain object on one channel and a different object on the other channel. Can this be done?